# Ajax запрос при отправке данных на почту

Tags: ajax, веб-программирование, frontend, передача-данных

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста! Пытаюсь на Open Server сделать отправку данных на почту без перезагрузки страницы но наткнулся на проблемку. Дело в том, что когда заполняю форму данными она не отправляется, однако, когда форма пустая и нажимаю на отправку то всё прекрасно отправляется и на почту приходит пустое письмо.

```js
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mailer/smart.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        $(this).find("input").val("");
        $('#consultation, #order').fadeOut();
        $('.modal, #thanks').fadeIn('slow');

        $('form').trigger('reset');
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<section class="modal">
            <div class="modal__window" id="consultation">
                <div class="modal__close">&times;</div>
                <div class="modal__title">Просто заполните форму заявки</div>
                <div class="modal__descr">и мы перезвоним вам в течении 10 минут</div>
                <form class="callBack__form modal__form" action="#" method="POST">
                    <input name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" type="text" required>
                    <input name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" type="tel" required>
                    <input name="email" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" type="email" required>

                    <button class="promo__btn button_submit">заказать кОНСУЛЬТАЦИЮ</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal__window" id="order">
                <div class="modal__close">&times;</div>
                <div class="modal__title">Ваш заказ:</div>
                <div class="modal__descr order-desc"></div>
                <form class="callBack__form modal__form" action="#" method="POST">
                    <input name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" type="text" required>
                    <input name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" type="tel" required>
                    <input name="email" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" type="email" required>

                    <button class="promo__btn button_submit">заказать кОНСУЛЬТАЦИЮ</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal__window mini" id="thanks">
                <div class="modal__close">&times;</div>
                <div class="modal__title">Спасибо за вашу заявку!</div>
                <div class="modal__descr">Наш менеджер свяжется с вами в ближайшее время!</div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

Форма отправки

[image: Форма отправки]

Окошко, открывающееся при успешной отправки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По идее, если данные не введены, то должно быть оповещение о том, что данные поля обязательны для ввода, однако, форма оправляется и выскакивает благодарственное окно!
Кто знает, как решить?
Спасибо!

Comment: Форму AJAX нужно отправлять не через submit а через клик по кнопке. Значения полей можно получать через .val()

Comment: Так же в вашем скрипте если произойдёт ошибка на сервере, всё равно напишет появится то что у вас при завершении запроса, с беком надо ощяться, через JSON

Comment: Вижу урок известного сайта, сама застряла на этом же моменте, и уже пару недель не могу сдвинуться с этой точки...